# Differences in re.sub notation

Tags: python, regex

I've gotten a bit tripped up using `re.sub` as it seems different than all the other python `re` functions/methods in how it does escaping. For example, the following expression:

```
>>> re.sub(r'\smd:', r'\s', '<tag md:new>text</tag>')
```

Which I would think would return: `<tag new>text</tag>`

Actually returns:

```
<tag\snew>text</tag>
```

With the `\s` unescaped. Do raw strings (`r'...'`) not work in the middle (`repl`) arg? Are there some guides as to how this should be used?

After doing a bit of trial-and-error with it, it seems like the way to use `re.sub` would be to 'capture' the space and pass it back as the replacement:

```
>>> re.sub(r'(\s)md:', r'\1', '<tag md:new>text</tag>')
'<tag new>text</tag>'
```

Comment: I don't see the point of using a raw string as the replacement.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't believe it is a matter of raw strings or not, but rather of the use of a regex pattern when the function only accepts a simple string value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your call to `re.sub`, the first parameter `r'\smd:'` should be a raw string, as you want the regex engine to parse the `\`, not Python. The second parameter `r'\s'` however doesn't need to be a raw string, as it won't be parsed by the regex engine, but you want to tell Python it should just be a space - so you can just pass it `' '`.

So, this would work:

```
re.sub(r'(\s)md:', ' ', '<tag md:new>text</tag>')
```

Another thing to note is that you're replacing `' md:'` with `' '` now, but you could instead just replace `'md:'` with `''` if it was preceded by a space and the nice way of doing that is:

```
re.sub(r'(?<=\s)(md:)', '', '<tag md:new>text</tag>')
```

It's not as short, but it is very clear about what you're actually doing and will work better in other cases where you know what goes before, but can't just replace it. This is called a regex lookbehind expression - not all engines will support it, but `re` for Python 3 currently does.

Answer (score 2):

`\s` is a character *set* (whitespaces), so it is not clear which character you expect the engine to replace the match with. Simply use a space () instead:

```
>>> re.sub(r'\smd:', r' ', '<tag md:new>text<tag>')
'<tag new>text<tag>'
```

Comment: Just to add on to this, according to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.sub) the function signature for `re.sub()` is: `re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)`. `repl` is the value used to replace occurrences of `pattern`, it therefore does not make sense for `repl` to be a regex expression or anything else.

Comment: In fact, running OP's code results in an error for me: "re.error: bad escape \s at position 0".